# Copy Elements of Stack into other Array without Changing Values

Tags: c, arrays, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>

int top = 1;
char stack[0][100];
//Assume stack [0] = "20"
//Assume stack [1] = "15"

for (int i=0; i<Loi; i++) {
    stack[i][99] = (char ) malloc(Loi + 1 * sizeof(char));
}
push("20");
push("15");

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<Loi; i++) {
        stack[i][99] = (char ) malloc(Loi + 1 * sizeof(char));
    }
    push("20");
    push("15");

    int tt = 3;
    char *tpStack[13];

    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        tpStack[k] = stack[tt];
        tt--;
    }

    pop();
    pop();

    printf("%s", tpStack[0]);
    printf("%s", tpStack[1]);
}

void pop () {
    stack[top][0] = '\0';
    top = top - 1;
}

char *push(char input[]) {
    top++;
    memcpy(stack[top], input, 100);
}
```

Hi, this is simplified code of a very complicated project. But I believe I got the important parts above. Ultimately, I have the Strings "20" and "15" in an array called stack. I want to copy these elements of the array into tpStack. I successfully do this (it works). However, when I call pop(), the elements in tpStack are no longer "20" and "15". I am new to C, but I am assuming this has to do with memory allocation of some sort. Have mercy, I'm not the best programmer.

Comment: 1. An array dimension of 0 is invalid.  2. please show how `stack` is initialized.

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Why are you casting the result of `malloc()` to `char`? You can't store a pointer in a `char` variable.

Comment: This is still not working code. Ex.: Loi is undefined.

Comment: `memcpy(stack[top], input, 100);` causes undefined behavior when `input` is less than 100 bytes long.

Comment: You don't need to use `malloc` at all. You allocated the memory when you declared the `stack` array.

Comment: 'stack' is still declared with zero size.  A 2D array [anything][0] is still zero size.

Answer (score 0):

`tpStack` just contains pointers to the arrays in `stack`. When you change `stack`, it also changes what `tpStack` points to.

You need to make copies of the stack elements if you don't want this to happen.

```
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    tpStack[k] = malloc(sizeof stack[tt]);
    memcpy(tpStack[k], stack[tt], sizeof stack[tt]);
    tt--;
}
```